# Can I use network cable for low voltage DC power?

Tags: current, dc, low-voltage, guitar-pedal

I'm a guitar player with a crazy idea for a 2 part bypass looper:

Enclosure A is just big enough to house 4 footswitches and an ethernet jack.

Enclosure B has 9V DPDT relays to route audio ins and outs. (9VDC is standard for guitar pedals)

Can I run power through CAT5 from the power source in Enclosure B to the switches in Enclosure A to make/break power to the coils of the relays back in Enclosure B?

The power supply would be one of 3 things: a 9V battery, an adapter with an output of 9VDC 500mA, or a "OneSpot" style adapter with an output of 9VDC 1700mA

The idea is to have a small controller mounted on the pedalboard with the larger enclosure hidden underneath, so the cable would only need to be 6ft at the most.

Could network cable handle this? Is there another compact solution that would be better? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Per the answer below, you're probably fine from an electrical standpoint. From a mechanical standpoint, you could be in for trouble. Most standard guitar pedals I've seen can withstand a direct hit from a mortar round. Most standard RJ45 jacks I've seen can barely withstand a dirty look. A guitar pedal lives in a pretty harsh environment; that cable is liable to get kicked within the first 17 seconds of usage. And when that happens, then that stupid little plastic tab will break off of the modular plug, and then the plug will keep coming unseated, and "you're gonna have a bad time"...

Comment: This question (10 months old) came up in my recommends. I'm very tired, which may be impeding* my understanding, but I'd love to see the project you made--maybe posted in an answer?

Comment: * Bad Wordplay Lovers--UNTIE!

Answer (score 1):

Modular Jacks are rated for 1.5A per pin including surge current to charge caps with hot insertion.

There are many varieties of modular jacks and cables or crimp plugs so you can gang contacts.  It is best for the longevity of "flash" ( u" thin) gold plating, that prevents rust, to avoid hot insertion ( live DC power) of the plug, rather make connections then turn on supply.

[Examples of Jacks](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/modular-connectors-jacks/366?k=mod%20jack&k=&pkeyword=mod%20jack&sv=0&sf=0&FV=ffe0016e&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=500)